# Understanding definition of Node.js's napi_value type

Tags: c++, c, node.js

I took a look inside the headers to see how the type `napi_value` is actually implemented and I don't understand it at all. (My C & C++ knowledge is limited) Can you please help me understand what is going on?

```
>> node_api.h
...
#include "napi_types.h"
...
typedef napi_value (*napi_addon_register_func)(napi_env env,
                                           napi_value exports);
...

>> node_api_types.h
...
// JSVM API types are all opaque pointers for ABI stability
// typedef undefined structs instead of void* for compile time type safety
typedef struct napi_value__ *napi_value;
...
typedef napi_value (*napi_callback)(napi_env env,
                                napi_callback_info info);
```

It's very confusing to me... The first and third typedefs kind of look like function signatures to me except the name is a pointer, i.e. my idea of a function signature is this:

```
typedef void function_SIG(void *a,void *b);
function_SIG *functionA_ptr; 
function_SIG *functionB_ptr;
```

The source is available on github:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_api.h
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_api_types.h

---

I downloaded and searched the whole repo (https://github.com/nodejs/node) for `napi_value__` but it only found this one reference... Maybe it is compiled with some V8 engine stuff?

Comment: The first and third aliases declare aliases for function pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and third ones are not defining `napi_value`. The first one defines `napi_addon_register_func`. The third one defines `napi_callback`.

This line:

```
typedef struct napi_value__ *napi_value;
```

defines `napi_value` as a pointer to a `struct napi_value__`.

---

"Opaque" means (usually) that the struct is defined in the library, but not defined in the header file. You can have pointers to a struct that is not defined.

Comment: But they don't seem to define the struct napi_value__ anywhere. Is that what they mean by opaqueness? I don't get it. How do they access what is inside of the structure? Should it be defined somewhere?

Comment: @thehorseisbrown "Opaque" means the struct is defined in the library, but not defined in the header file.

Comment: What kind of library? Can it be defined in some source file? The header with `napi_value__` only includes `#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: It will be defined in a different header file that is part of node.js. You might or might not actually have this header file on your system. You don't have to define a struct in order to have pointers to it.

Comment: Then you might not have that file on your system.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
typedef napi_value (*napi_addon_register_func)(napi_env env,
                                           napi_value exports);
```

is a declaration of the alias name `napi_addon_register_func` for the type of pointer to function that has the return type `napi_value` and two parameters of the type `napi_env` and `napi_value` .

To make this declaration more simpler you could rewrite it in C++ (not C) as an alias declaration

```
using napi_addon_register_func = napi_value ( * )(napi_env env, napi_value exports);
```

The same is valid for this typedef

```
typedef napi_value (*napi_callback)(napi_env env,
                                napi_callback_info info);
```

that is it is also declares the alias name `napi_callback` for the type of pointer to function with the return type `napi_value` and two parameters of the type `napi_env` and `napi_callback_info`.

As for this typedef

```
typedef struct napi_value__ *napi_value;
```

then there is declared the alias name `napi_value` for the type pointer to structure of the type `struct napi_value__`.

These declarations

```
typedef void function_SIG(void *a,void *b);
function_SIG *functionA_ptr; 
function_SIG *functionB_ptr;
```

if you want to introduce an alias name for the type pointer to function should be rewritten like

```
typedef void function_SIG(void *a,void *b);
typedef function_SIG *functionA_ptr;
```

Comment: Does it mean that in my example of a function signature, I can also do: `typedef void (*function_SIG)(void *a,void *b);` and `function_SIG functionA_ptr`?

Comment: @thehorseisbrown The first one is a declaration of an alias to function pointer and the second one is a declaration of an object (pointer) of the type that is of the pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct napi_value__ *napi_value;
```

Defines `napi_value` as a type alias for `struct napi_value__*`.  The placement of the `*` is valid but confusing IMO since it is part of the type, not the type name.  Like:

```
typedef struct napi_value__* napi_value;
```

The definition

```
typedef napi_value (*napi_callback)(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info);
```

defines a type `napi_callback` which is a pointer to a function returning a `napi_value` and taking parameters of type `napi_env` and `napi_callback_info` respectively.  So for example given a function:

```
napi_value someFunction( napi_env env, napi_callback_info info ) ;
```

you can create a pointer:

```
napi_callback mycallback = someFunction ;
```

The callback can then be invoked by:

```
mycallback( env, info ) ;
```

It is a way (amongst other things) for a library to link to user-supplied code that is not known at the time that the library is built.

```
typedef napi_value (*napi_addon_register_func)(napi_env env, napi_value exports);
```

Is another function pointer type defining the type `napi_addon_register_func` a pointer-to-function returning `napi_value` with `napi_env`, and `napi_value` type arguments.

Comment: Note about `*` placement: while I tend to agree that `int* ptrToInt` is more intuitive than `int *ptrToInt` it's easy to get burned when declaring variables on the same line, e.g. `int* ptr, oopsNotPtr;`

Comment: @jacobq : Well I have a rule about that too - don't do it.  For exactly that reason.